# push messages from myapplication through XMPP

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, xmpp

I am about to develop an application, in which the windows application will receive messages from the server when there is a new entry in server database. I am planning to do the same using xmpp and c# in asp.net. Is that a better way?

The scenerio is like this: Whenever a new entry is inserted into my sqlserver database, my windows application should be notified with that new entry. i.e. I want to push the message from the server to the windows application. How can I push the message using xmpp? Can I set the server as my company server? Or should I have to use jabber server itself?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are multiple instances of the client running, then using some form of pubsub, like XMPP pubsub would be an appropriate solution.  There are many pubsub solutions available, you will have to select the appropriate one based on all your requirements and/or restrictions.

If this functionality is considered business critical, then you should definitely be using your own server.

I don't know if any of the public XMPP servers have pubsub enabled and configurable by the public or not.